# Using save in after_find callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a status field that needs to be updated to `expired` if the status is `new` and has passed a certain period of time.

Is there any issue with doing a `save` inside the after_find callback to update the record when it is loaded? Is there any other more appropriate callback for this?

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is have a periodic background job (sidekiq/delayed_job or the like) that will find all freshly-expired records and update their flag. Much less surprising than a write in an `after_find` callback.

Something to think about: suppose that you load 100 records for showing in a view and find all of them expired. So instead of 1 query, you perform 101 query (one select and 100 updates). It directly affects page load time and it gets worse the more records you load at once. Whereas in my proposed approach it's only two queries, one of them out-of-band mass-update, not affecting page load at all.

Answer (score 1):

There's no inherent issue with it, it will work. `after_find` is called anytime an existing record is instantiated. `save` inserts the attributes into the database, but doesn't re-instantiate the object, so you don't have to worry about unwanted recursion by calling `save` inside that callback. A similar callback would be `after_initialize`, the only difference being that `after_initialize` is called on new objects as well. `after_find` would be more appropriate.

Whether or not it's the best approach to the problem though is debatable. It's probably the easiest and quickest to set up. But you're relying on objects to be instantiated by your program for data integrity. What if you need to do a database dump? Sergio's suggestion is probably a better approach overall.